# Передача данных между двумя ViewModels - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

Из заголовка понятно, что я пытаюсь передать данные из 1vm во 2vm.
Использую BottomNavigationBar вместе с Jetpack Navigation.
Экраны очень простые. в `ScheduleScreen` я выбираю дни (пн-вс) кликая по textButtin. Если день выбран то записываю его в массив. Например если выбрана среда, то массив

```
daysChoosen(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Этот массив хранится в vm - `ScheduleScreenVM`. Теперь я хочу переключится на `CalendarScreen`, у которой свом vm - `CalendarScreenVM` и увидеть массив из `ScheduleScreenVM`.
[ScheduleScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tc8vf.png).
После правок из ответов я попытался создать бд и репо.

daysTable:

```
@Entity()
data class DaysChoosenEntity(
    var daysChoosen: Int,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int? = null
) {
}
```

daysDAO:

```
@Dao
interface DaysChoosenDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertDays(days: DaysChoosenEntity)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteDays(days: DaysChoosenEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM dayschoosenentity")
    fun getDays(): Flow<List<DaysChoosenEntity>>
}
```

daysDB:

```
@Database(
    entities = [DaysChoosenEntity::class],
    version = 1
)
abstract class DaysChoosenDB: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val daysChoosenDAO: DaysChoosenDAO

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "dayschoosen_db"
    }
}
```

daysRepo:

```
class DaysChoosenRepositoryImpl(
    private val dao: DaysChoosenDAO
): DaysChoosenRepository {

    override fun getDaysChoosen(): Flow<List<DaysChoosenEntity>> {
        return dao.getDays()
    }

    override suspend fun insertDaysChoosen(days: DaysChoosenEntity) {
        dao.insertDays(days)
    }

    override suspend fun deleteDaysChoosen(days: DaysChoosenEntity) {
        dao.deleteDays(days)
    }
}
```

daysUseCases:

```
data class DaysChoosenUseCase (
    val getDaysChoosen: GetDaysChoosen,
    val deleteDaysChoosen: DeleteDaysChoosen,
    val addDaysChoosen: AddDaysChoosen
)
```

для начала я бы хотел просто добавить день. so addDaysChoose:

```
class AddDaysChoosen(
    private val repository: DaysChoosenRepository
) {

    suspend operator fun invoke(days: DaysChoosenEntity){
        repository.insertDaysChoosen(days)
    }
}
```

ScheduleScreenVM:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ScheduleScreenVM @Inject constructor (
    private val daysChoosenUseCase: DaysChoosenUseCase
        ): ViewModel() {

    //states
    val allDays = daysChoosenUseCase.getDaysChoosen
    var daysChoosen by mutableStateOf(mutableListOf(0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

    var rememem by mutableStateOf(
        SnapshotStateList<Boolean>().also {
            for(day in 0..6){
                it.add(false)
            }
        }
    )

    //events
    fun snapChanged(int: Int){ rememem[int] = !rememem[int] }

    fun insertDays(int: Int) = viewModelScope.launch {
        daysChoosenUseCase.addDaysChoosen(
            DaysChoosenEntity(daysChoosen = int)
        )
    }
}
```

Вот тут начинаются небольшие сложности. Чтобы добавить день в таблицу мне нужно использовать insertDays function from VM. например

```
DaysOfWeekButton(
    onClick =
    {
        viewModel.snapChanged(day)
        if(viewModel.rememem[day]) {
        viewModel.daysChoosen.set(day, 1)
        viewModel.insertDays(1)
    }
    else {
        viewModel.daysChoosen.set(day, 0)
        viewModel.insertDays(0)
    }
},
```

Результат я пытаюсь посмотреть на экране примерно так (probably)

```
Text("${viewModel.allDays}")
```

Я еще ничего не успел проверить, но уже столкнулся с проблемой

```
.data_source.DaysChoosenDAO cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Не очень понимаю почему она появилась и как ее исправить(нужно ли добавлять в AppModule @Provide для функции, которая возвращает DAO если он есть в репозитории). В итоге вопрос остался таким же. Как мне сохранить данные в таблицу и считать ее.

Comment: Все зависит от того, как у вас делается навигация - используется ли NavHost в котором навигация через параметры (или же использовать hilt для shared viewmodel) или же просто одна viewmodel где screen просто меняются.

Comment: "В итоге вопрос остался таким же"  - вопрос кардинально изменился. Передача данных - это аргументы к `navController.navigate()` или через BackStackEntry (не ваш случай ибо у вас все на одном уровне) или вообще один общий ViewModel уровнем повыше. А "сохранить данный в базе данных" - это просто "сохранить данные в базе данных". И то, что они в другом месте могут быть извлечены - не является передачей данных.

Comment: @vitidev Вы внесли больше ясности. тогда в каких случаях можно и нужно передавать данные через `navController`?

Comment: Когда их нужно передать, а не хранить. Данные в базе данных никуда не передаются - они всего лишь там хранятся и могу читаться кому нужно. В вашем случае вряд ли нужно передавать - у вас 2 экрана на одном уровне (у них нет даже кнопки назад). И раз есть NavHost, значит логически это разные экраны и они просто работают с разделяемыми данными, которым место в базе данных или в общей ViewModel. Но использовать базу для "записали чтобы в другом месте прочитали и сразу удалили" неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

а причем тут Jetpack Compose ? идея архитектуру как раз в том, чтобы они подходила под любую реализацию UI.
вам надо передать даныне из 1-ой ВМ в другую.

Вариант №1.
если у вас фрагменты - то вы можете использовать `sharedViewModel`.
это тип ВМ, у которой владельцем является Активити и она привязывает к ее ЖЦ.
таким образом все фрагменты в этой Активити смог получить "общие" данные.

Вариант №2.
у вас не фрагменты. (стоит задумать о том, чтобы использовать их).
вам надо создать какой Репозиторий, который будет статичным (сингл в DI).
1ая ВМ кладет/ложит туда данные. 2ая ВМ - забирает их оттуда.
да, вы можете подключить Рум, но это все таки более тяжелая библиотека. и данные будут "переживать" ЖЦ приложения (т.е. храниться постоянно).

Comment: разве в JC нужно использовать фрагменты? Я имею в виду, что не уверен в этом. Экран рисуем в Composable функции. Потом кидаем их в  NavHost для навигации. В любом случае я попытался изучить вопрос и создать репозиторий. Пожалуйста проверьте меня